# ggplot: Prevent year end data showing up as the following year

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, lubridate

This seems like a simple question, but I couldn't find an easy way to do this and similar questions didn't seem to address my issue.

I am plotting year end data and want it to show up on the x-axis as that year, not the following year.  For example, 12/31/2015 data reflects what happened in 2015, not 2016, but the plot will show it as 2016.

I could mutate the data and add the year-only value in the mutated column  (12/31/2015 becomes 2015) and use that to plot the data set, but I was hoping there was something simpler in case I want to plot other time periods (quarters, months, etc.).

**So 2 questions:**

1) Is there an easy way to automatically plot year end data to represent the year in which it occurred as opposed to the following year?

2) Why does ggplot remove 2 rows when I tried to adjust the x-axis scale, resulting in a worse plot (test_p2)?

**Reproducible example**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

# Sample data
mydates   <- as.Date(c( "2015-12-31", "2016-12-31", "2017-12-23", "2015-12-31", "2016-12-31", "2017-12-23"))
variables <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3))
values    <- c(2, 4, -4, -5, -10, 5)
test_df   <- data.frame(mydates, variables, values)

# plot
test_p <- ggplot(test_df, aes(x = mydates, y = values, fill = variables)) + geom_col(position = "dodge")
test_p
```

[image]

Adjust x-axis scale:

```
BeginPlotDate   = "2015-12-31"
EndPlotDate     = "2017-12-23"

test_p2 <- test_p + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year",
                                 date_labels = "%Y",
                                 limits      = as.Date(c(BeginPlotDate, EndPlotDate))
                                 )
test_p2
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're normally supposed to not ask two questions at once, but in any case, here are two answers:

**Question 1**

What happens is that ggplot2 rounds the dates to the nearest year, and that's the next year. I think the easiest approach to address this issue is to simply subtract 12 months in the `aes()` statement:

```
test_p <- ggplot(test_df,
                 aes(x = mydates %m-% months(12),
                     y = values, fill = variables)) + 
          geom_col(position = "dodge")
test_p
```

[image]

The only downside is that now you need to manually adjust the title of the x axis, but that is straightforward, e.g. with `xlab()`:

```
test_p + xlab("my dates")
```

[image]

**Question 2**

You're setting the starting point of the x axis to "2015-12-31", and that's exactly what ggplot does. You need to set the starting point to an earlier date (about 6 months earlier) to have enough room for the bars you want to plot there. (Here, I actually have to set it 18 months earlier because I also subtract 12 months from the dates, see above.)

```
BeginPlotDate   = "2014-06-01"
EndPlotDate     = "2017-08-01"

test_p2 <- test_p + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year",
                                 date_labels = "%Y",
                                 limits      = as.Date(c(BeginPlotDate, EndPlotDate))
)
test_p2
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Claus.  Technical question:  When I use your suggestion, the warning message says: "Removed 3 rows containing missing values (geom_col)".  I interpreted the message as though somehow values were missing in the underlying data.  You are saying the thickness of the bars gets represented as time (and hence the scale needs to be adjusted) even though I am trying to represent a value for a singular year?  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. When values get removed that generally means they fall outside the axis range, so you need to extend the range until they are included. This is a date scale, so you need to extend the date range. May seem a bit counter-intuitive, but that's how it works.

Answer (score 1):

There is a rather simple solution to the problem: Just use `year(mydates)`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

ggplot(test_df, aes(x = year(mydates), y = values, fill = variables)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

When plotting `Date` or `POSIXct`, `ggplot2` assumes a continuous scale which is suitably formated by placing nicely labeled tick marks at the appropriate places, e.g., there will be tick mark on 2016-01-01 which is labelled "2016". So, if your data point has an x value of 2015-12-31 it will be plotted near the 2016-01-01 tick mark. This is useful for daily or weekly data but not in your use case.

#### Edit

The OP has pointed out that he needs a date axis because he wants to plot monthly and quarterly data as well.

In case the OP wants *to overlay* monthly, quarterly, and yearly data in *one plot* using a continuous date axis, then I strongly discourage to use bar charts for this purpose, especially when dodged.

Bar charts are normally used for discrete data. The height of the bar conveys the information. Usually, the width has no meaning and can be chosen arbitrarily or aesthetically pleasing.

If the OP is insisting on a date axis then the width *should* have a meaning. For instance, the horizontal extension could convey the information which time period each value is assigned to, e.g.,

```
ggplot(test_df, aes(x = floor_date(mydates, "year"), xend = mydates, 
                    y = values, yend = values, colour = variables)) + 
  geom_segment(size = 1) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Here, the line segments start a the begin of the year and extend to the given end date. This visualizes that `values` represent yearly values. Dodging doesn't make any sense her, so the colour code is the only distinction between `variables`.

A more complex example (using especially made up data) is showing monthly values, quarterly and yearly averages in one chart:

```
ggplot(month_df) + 
  aes(x = mydates, xend = floor_date(mydates, first(period)), 
      xmin = floor_date(mydates, first(period)), xmax = mydates,
      y = values, yend = values, ymin = 0, ymax = values, 
      fill = variables, shape = variables) + 
  geom_rect(data = year_df, alpha = 0.5)  +
  geom_segment(aes(colour = variables), data = quarter_df, size = 1) + 
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

However, the chart is rather convoluted and the chart's message is difficult to explain and perceive.

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
# create monthly dummy data
month_df <- data.table(
  # last day of month
  mydates = rep(seq(as.Date("2015-02-01"), length.out = 36L, by = "month") - days(1L), 2L),
  variables = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 36L),
  values = c(sinpi((1:36) / 18), cospi((1:36) / 12)),
  period = "month"
)
# aggregate by quarter
quarter_df <- month_df[, .(values = mean(values), period = "quarter"), 
     by = .(mydates = ceiling_date(mydates, "quarter") - days(1L), variables)]
# aggregate by year
year_df <- month_df[, .(values = mean(values), period = "year"), 
     by = .(mydates = ceiling_date(mydates, "year") - days(1L), variables)]
```

Comment: Thanks Uwe.  The only issue I see with your solution is that x then no longer becomes a date format and becomes a numeric.  This is fine for part 1, but throws an error in part 2 for if I wanted to adjust the x-scale.

Comment: Why do you still need to adjust the x scale? And, if still required, you can also adjust the scale of a numeric  axis appropriately. Perhaps, there is more behind your question which you haven't disclosed yet?

Comment: If I wanted to change the BeginPlotDate and EndPlotDate with a larger time series.  I just showed a minimum reproducible example here.

Comment: Once the scale is continuous you can adjust limits with `scale_x_continuous()`. I don't see a problem here.

Comment: Uwe, since I have a large time series with dates, I wanted to be able to enter a beginning date and ending date to plot the time periods of interest.  Once the dates become numeric, then I have to worry about code elsewhere that is expecting a date but instead gets fed a numeric (whether it is other formatting or some other part of the longer code).  As I mentioned in the original post, I might want to plot other time periods like quarters or months which will be date values.

Comment: Do you want to plot quarters and months on the same chart as the year values?